# How to launch an app from foreground/background service?

Tags: java, android, launch, background-service, foreground-service

I am new to the android development in java so apologies if this question is so simple.

Basically I am aiming for restarting the application after it crashes without user manually pressing the app icon or notification that app has failed via for example foreground service. I have tried launching app using getPackageManager in a "Foreground service of another app" , below is the code snipper of my foreground service as an example :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    startLogging();


    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    PowerManager powerManager = null;
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    }
                    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
                    wakeLock.acquire();

                    while (true) {
                        Log.d( "Service", "Service is running...");

                        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("app.tester.com");
                        if (intent != null) {
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

..........
..........

}

However, my foreground service is only able to launch the crashed app if the foreground's main activity is in foreground aswell i.e app whose foreground service is responsible for launching the crashing app is on user's screen.

I can also work with if there's an app x which can launch this crashing app , if app x is even in recent task of phone.

I would appreciate if there's any solution that can just restart this crashing app via another app which is in recent task or foreground service or even background service.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  This was a recent change in Android.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts for the restrictions and brief times where you can launch things from the background.

Comment: So basically it is impossible to restart my app without user's interaction ?

Comment: Correct.  What you should be asking is "why did my app crash" and fix that.

Comment: its for a research purpose honestly. What if I create a foreground service that does the heavy load work for my app where as my app in general won't be using any significant memory. Under low memory conditions, will the android kill my whole app or just the foreground service. If I can somehow make OS just kill the service rather than APP, I can auto restart the service from APP using for example Broadcast receiver. I will really appreciate if you could answer this. TIA!!

Comment: @Shazer Use WorkManager.  That's the system that's been created for doing long background processing.  You should also consider whether Android is the proper OS to do something like this on.  Embedded Linux may be a better answer.

Comment: thanks alot for advising the work manager. I did some reading on it and it does seem to have potential to fulfil my tasks. Hopefully this might help. Once again thanks :)